# msdeploy.axd returns 404

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

I'm trying to setup webdeploy on IIS8, but why am I getting 404 when accessing both https://[servername]:8172/msdeploy.axd and https://localhost:8172/msdeploy.axd locally.

I've installed management service.

I've installed webdeploy 3.5 using web platform installer. In Program and Features a changed the instalation of webdeploy to include all features including the handler.

In IIS Manager I've chosen Configure Web Deploy Publishing for default website's context menu.

I've restarted management service.

when i tried https://[servername]:8172/msdeploy.axd I was asked to enter credentials and accept the certificate. after that I got 404.

I've uninstalled webdeploy and installed using MSI manually including all features.

restarted entire server.

getting 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can open the service from a browser.  I attempted that against a dev server that we deploy to many times a day and also received a 404.  I would try deploying from VS instead as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Also if anyone comes here and is using Visual Studio Publish dialog and the "Validate Connection" button fails: do **NOT** use the button when **creating**. Just click `Ok`, then `Edit` (in `More actions` menu).

In the Connection tab, click Validate Connection. This time it will asks you to accept an invalid certificate (since you likely self-signed it on your server). Accept it and the connection should go through.